# How to create an entity group and save entities using objectify in the datastore

Tags: android, google-app-engine, junit, objectify

Objectify documentation (https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities) is very shallow to me and gives only one example of saving an entity in the datastore.

I want to save like 5 entities under a group called **Presidents** in my development GAE server using android studio. with my understanding of the documentation, this is how i should do it

```
@Entity
public class Presidents{
 @Id Long id;
String name;
int age;

public Presidents(Long pId, String pName, int pAge){
 id = pId;
 name = pName
 age = pAge;
}
}
```

I then register my class and using it like this(Am using junit to perform the test)

```
public PresidentsOfKenyaTest{

 static{
 ObjectifyService.register(Presidents.class);
 }

  private final LocalServiceTestHelper helper =
  new LocalServiceTestHelper(new LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig());


@Before
public void setUp() {
    helper.setUp();
}
@Test
Public void nameOfPresidents(){
Presidents p1 = new Presidents(new Long(1),Daniel,88);
Presidents p2 = new Presidents(new Long(2),Mwai,81);
Presidents p3 = new Presidents(new Long(3),Daniel,70);

 ofy().save().entities.(p1,p2,p3).now();
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    helper.tearDown();
}
}
```

However, when i run a Junit test  of the above class in android studio, am getting the exception below

```
 java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:com.google.appengine
 .tools.development.LocalRpcService: Provider com.google.appengine.api.
datastore.dev.LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service could not be instantiated


at PresidentsOfKenyaTest.tearDown(PresidentsOfKenyaTest.java:40)

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.appengine.api.datastore.dev.LocalCloudDatastoreV1Service
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:380)
... 40 more
```

**Question**

- Am i saving my entities the right way?
- What is causing the exception above to be thrown and how should i solve it?

Comment: Have you added the GAE unit testing jars to your classpath? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting

Comment: There are two different issues here. If you want each of your `Presidents` entities (I would use the singular, `President`) you need a [`@Parent`](https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Entities#parent-relationships) to define the ancestor key. But make sure you understand [entity groups](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/entities) first.  If you write your `@Test nameOfPresidents()` to check the entities are written you can see if that's working.  The `tearDown()` (where your error is occurring) will run after the test.

Comment: @tx802         How can i solve the error occurring at `tearDown()` ?

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston   yes i have. like this                                **testCompile com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.26**
    **testCompile com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.8.2**
    **testCompile com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs:1.8.2**
    **testCompile com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk:1.8.2**
    **testCompile com.google.appengine:appengine-testing:1.8.2**

Comment: @tx802         How do i define the `@parent key`? am not understanding objectify documentation